# Laravel 5.5 get route path for a named route?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I access route path for a named route in Laravel 5.5? As far as I've searched for this syntax, I haven't found such.

Comment: route('name') ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Name Route Path in Web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'ModelController@index')->name('model.index');
Route::get('/create', 'ModelController@create')->name('model.create');
Route::get('/edit/{paramerter}', 'ModelController@edit')->name('model.edit');
```

**Accessing Route Path:**
    `route('model.index')`

**Passing Parameter:**
    `route('model.edit', ['parameter'=> $value])`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was so simple that I missed it... Using syntax route('model.index') worked magic :)

Answer (score 1):

To directly redirect to a named route, use:

```
return redirect()->route('NAME');
```

To see the path to a named route, use:

```
echo route('NAME');
```